# DOS For if statement to look for file in multiple directories

Tags: loops, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, dos

I'm trying to use the following DOS statement to look for 1st level folders that do not have important.txt.

```
for /d %X in (M:\*) do if not exist important.txt echo %X
```

This statement runs, but the if portion does not run properly, always returning that the file is missing even when it exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just `if NOT EXIST m:\important.txt (echo yes)` does not need loop

Comment: Are you really using MS-DOS or are you talking about the commandline in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing the existance of the file in the current directory only because you didn't prefix the folder name. Try `for /d %X in (M:*) do if not exist %X\important.txt echo %X`
and see what changes.
Another note: you scan directories from the current directory on M: on. This might be M:\ or some other directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
for /d %%X in (c:\tmp\*) do if not exist %%X\important.txt echo %%X
```

Note the double `%%` necessary for `FOR` in batch files.